# onchange only detects first checkbox of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is the div

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 pre-scrollable" id="all-menus-div">
        <h3 class="text-center">Tum menu listesi</h3>
        <div class="list-group" id="all-menus-checkboxes" th:each="menu : ${allMenusList}">
            <input th:id="${menu.id}" th:text="${menu.item}" th:value="${menu.item}" type="checkbox"/>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" disabled id="add-menus-to-role-btn" type="submit">Ekle</button>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-success" id="update-menus-for-role-btn" type="submit">Rolu guncelle</button>
</div>
```

it gets from model object.

This is the function of it for **onchange**:

```
    $('#all-menus-checkboxes').on('change', function () { // on change of state
var addButton = document.getElementById('add-menus-to-role-btn');
        lengthOfCheckedAllMenus = $('#all-menus-div :checked').length;
        debugger;
        console.log(" lengthOfCheckedAllMenus: " + lengthOfCheckedAllMenus);

        addButton.disabled = lengthOfCheckedAllMenus <= 0;
    });
```

it calls this function when I click the first checkbox only. And i can see only the log at this time. So, only button disabled becomes **false** only when i click the first one.

When i click others, nothing happens, no logs.

But when i click for example second one, then click first one, it shows **2** of them are selected.

Why is that?

Simple allMenuslist:

```
[MenuDTO{id=1, href='/check-deposit-money', menuName='Kontrol-Onay Ekranları', roles=[RoleDTO{id=1, name='ADMIN'}], iconName='null', item='Cüzdana Para Yükleme - Kontrol', className='null'}]
```

Comment: Id's need to be unique. Try class selector instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. onchange event must to bind on the `<input>`.
2. bind event must to after `<input>` appended.

But your `<input>` like by dynamic generation, recommend use 'event delegation':

add class to `<input>`.

```
<input class="all-menus-checkboxes" />
```

use event delegation.

```
<script>
  $('#all-menus-div').on('change', '.all-menus-checkboxes', function () { ... }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $('#all-menus-checkboxes > input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () { // on change of state
var addButton = document.getElementById('add-menus-to-role-btn');
        lengthOfCheckedAllMenus = $('#all-menus-div :checked').length;
        debugger;
        console.log(" lengthOfCheckedAllMenus: " + lengthOfCheckedAllMenus);

        addButton.disabled = lengthOfCheckedAllMenus <= 0;
    });
```

Comment: I have lots of inputs in other divs also. So, i only need for that div.

Comment: use the css selector '#all-menus-checkboxes > input[type=checkbox]'